# Month navigation sidebar in blog section?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a blog section in a drupal website, built with Views. I want to add a sidebar with month navigation (as in each mont is listed with the number of posts, etc). How can I do this, preferably with Views?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal views can create views which allow you to select and list or summarise lists of nodes by various fields including the date related fields. You can do this by adding an argument, and then setting how the view behaves when no argument is supplied.

Are you looking for something along the following lines?

*March 2010 (3)

February 2010 (12)

January 2010 (7)
... etc.*

Create a view called Monthly Summary, and add an "argument" 'Node: Created year + month'.

Then use the options on the argument to select the 'action to take if argument is not present'.  Select 'Summary, sorted descending' to create list with most recent month at top.

Watch out for sorting issues - this choice of how you sort the monthly summary in the argument settings will override the usual views sort order. This caught me out for a while.

Comment: Thank you sean, this sounds more or less like what I need. I will try it and see how it goes

Comment: Ok, I've configured the argument as you told me, but now I have no idea how to display the list of months with the post count for each one, and an hyperlink in each month to provide the argument.
Could you please give me some advice? Thank you

Comment: Hi Oalo, it sounds like you have created a new view and set up all the defaults. A single view can be displayed in several different ways based on same set of default parameters.  From the view select the dropdown 'block' and click 'add display'.  Remember to save the view and head over to admin / blocks to drag and drop the new block into place and set which pages the block appears on.  There is some documentation on views at http://drupal.org/project/views/
and more useful information at http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/

Comment: If I undestand it correctly, the view oalo has created only handles the landing pages e.g. /blog/archive/yyyy/md . He now needs a view which outputs a list of links to /blog/archive/2010/12 , /blog/archive/2010/11 etc. but only for months with posts. Having played around just now my feeling is that Views' concept of distinctness (distinct based on nid) means you simply cannot do this with a node view: you get identical links for every blogpost in a given month/year. So you need custom code, unless there's a module out there that supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date)/[Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) modules? Some more details about the [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module (from its project page):

> This module will display any Views date field in calendar formats, including CCK date fields, node created or updated dates, etc. Switch between year, month, and day views. Back and next navigation is provided for all views. Lots of the Calendar functionality comes from the Date module, so any time you update the Calendar module you should be sure you also update to the latest version of the Date module at the same time.
>
> See also [Date iCal](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_ical), a project that contains code and features needed to either import or export dates using iCal feeds. The functionality that used to be in the Calendar iCal module has been moved into that module.